# How to implement rest login by using Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Here's my code for login controller.java and AccessToken.java that is returned after login process

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class Controller {


 @Autowired AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
 @Autowired UserService userService;



 @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public AccessToken logsin(
         @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request,  HttpSession session
         ) {


     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken  token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (request.getId(), request.getPassword());
     Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
     session.setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
               SecurityContextHolder.getContext());



     AccessToken token1 = new AccessToken();
     token1.setUsername(authentication.getName());
     token1.setAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities());
     token1.setToken(session.getId());

     Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

     System.out.println("a.isAuthenticated : "+ a.isAuthenticated());



     return token1;
 }
```

,

```
public class AccessToken {


private String username;
private Collection authorities;
private String token;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public Collection getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}
public void setAuthorities(Collection authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}
public String getToken() {
    return token;
}
public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

}

if I send a request to '/user/login' the login process, the value of  System.out.println("a.isAuthenticated : "+ a.isAuthenticated()); is 'true'

and I get back AccessToken 
for example,

```
{
    "username": "myid1",
    "authorities": [
        {
            "authority": "user"
        }
    ],
    "token": "3D31F32383859DB145320941122CA189"
}
```

And I set a filter class and HttpSessionStrategy bean for token authentication

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("filter!");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-auth-token");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "x-auth-token");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

public void destroy() {}

}
```

,

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

@Autowired UserService userService;
@Autowired AuthenticationProvider provider;
@Autowired BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
         .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/user/login").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/main").authenticated()
               .antMatchers("main").authenticated()
               .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()

               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()

          .logout()
          ;              
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.userDetailsService(userService)
          .passwordEncoder(encoder);

}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Bean
public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
          return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
}
```

After that I sent a request to another url that needs authentication with header

'x-auth-token = 3D31F32383859DB145320941122CA189'

However the server responded with 403 forbidden error

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need enable the springHttpSession and inmemory session Repository.

Please see [here](https://github.com/chao-luo/stackoverflow/tree/Q56352304) for the example code

Get token by username & password

`curl -u user:password -v http://localhost:8080/api/token`

Get me by token

`curl -H "x-auth-token: $token" -v http://localhost:8080/me`